# What does tinder (the app name) mean?

Tags: meaning

What does Tinder mean?
I mean the name of the popular dating app.
Is it a word or a derivation or misspelling of an English words or expression?
Or is it just a fantasy word?
I am not a native English speaker and other than the suffix 'er it doesn't mean anything. Does Tind mean something, is there a verb to Tind.
Thanks

Comment: No, *tender* means soft. *Tinder* in English is something used to light one's fire, which I suppose might be relevant in a lateral-thinking way [ODO on *tinder*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tinder).

Comment: @developerwjk - sorry, was that a joke?  Tinder <> Tender.

Comment: @KristinaLopez, I noticed that after I read over it again right after clicking "add comment." Lol.

Comment: Some background from here (http://www.brit.co/tech-company-names/):
"10. Tinder: What started out as “Matchbox” eventually became Tinder after the founders consulted a thesaurus. They stuck with the fire theme, liking the idea that their app could create a romantic spark."

Comment: @developerwjk - lol!  It would give a whole new meaning to Elvis Presley's "Love Me Tinder" song.  :-D

Answer (score 8):

Tinder is an app that makes matches. Starts the spark, so to say.

This is an excerpt from [Rewind and Capture](http://www.rewindandcapture.com/why-is-tinder-called-tinder/), which explains why they chose the name:

> The idea of setting a spark, of starting a fire, for romantic relationships was always the log-cabin foundation for Tinder, which was originally called Matchbox. According to the [Milwaukee Business Journal](http://www.bizjournals.com/milwaukee/print-edition/2014/03/28/all-in-a-name-why-is-it-called-tinder.html), co-founder Jonathan Badeen admitted the trio decided against Matchbox but were still struck by the thought.
>
> “We still liked that sort of fire theme, so actually we looked through a dictionary, a thesaurus, something like that, looking for fire-related words,” he said. Eventually settling on Tinder, which [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tinder) defines as, “dry material (such as wood or grass) that burns easily and can be used to start a fire.” Worst case, “people will either get it, and they’ll say, ‘Oh — tinder: fire,’ or they don’t get it and they think it’s some clever misspelling of the word ‘tender,’” said Badeen.

In case you missed it, ["tinder"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tinder), in plain English, refers to a:

> dry material (such as wood or grass) that burns easily and can be used to start a fire.